# My flexform configuration doesn't show up

Tags: typo3

I tried to to make it possible to configure the FE plugins of my own extension. The flexform configurion I tried doesn't show up in the backend.
Why it doesn't work and what do I need to change?

I'm working with Typo3 8.7.3.

Here are the relevant code parts:

**ext_tables.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
  'Fmogge.'.$extKey,
  'Nextcourse',
  'Nächste Kurse'
);

$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);
$frontendpluginName = 'Nextcourse';
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName).'_'.strtolower($frontendpluginName);
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Configuration/FlexForms/Nextcourse.xml');
```

**Configuration/FlexForms/Nextcourse.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Optionen</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <settings.ort>
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>Ort wählen</label>
                        <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <items type="array">
                                <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
                                </numIndex>
                            </items>
                            <foreign_table>tx_coursemanager_domain_model_ort</foreign_table>
                              <foreign_table_where>
                                 AND elterndatensatz = 0
                              </foreign_table_where>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
                </settings.ort>
            </el>
        </ROOT>
    </sDEF>
</sheets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `GLOBAL` variables like below. it's work for me.

Just replace below line in your `ext_tables.php` file

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ext_tables.php change syntax of *$extKey* to *$_EXTKEY* which will solve your issue, like:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
  'Fmogge.'.$_EXTKEY,
  'Nextcourse',
  'Nächste Kurse'
);

$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);
$frontendpluginName = 'Nextcourse';
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName).'_'.strtolower($frontendpluginName);
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Configuration/FlexForms/Nextcourse.xml');
```

Hint: Avoid using $_EXTKEY in the future, use extension key as string instead. It has been changed in core and various 3rd party extensions. It helps, when you move such configs to folder Configuration/TCA/.. where $_EXTKEY is not available.

Your flexform file misses closing tag for *T3DataStructure* like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Optionen</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <settings.ort>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Ort wählen</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <items type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                                <foreign_table>tx_coursemanager_domain_model_ort</foreign_table>
                                  <foreign_table_where>
                                     AND elterndatensatz = 0
                                  </foreign_table_where>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.ort>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
<T3DataStructure>
```

Comment: and it should be $GLOBALS['TCA'] instead of $TCA

Comment: $GLOBALS['TCA'] does the trick! You saved my day. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as solution.

Comment: Usage of $TCA[TABLENAME] is obsolete but still working in TYPO3 CMS 8